# Applying custom style to the mask on click of overlay panel in sencha touch 2.2.1

Tags: sencha-touch-2.1

I have created a button. On click of the button an overlay panel is made visible.
Since modal = true , rest of the page is masked. (from top = 0px)
My requirement is that I need to mask only a part of my page(from top = 125 px) .
I have tried to override the css class **.x-mask** . But it didn't help !!
Here is the sample code ,

```
xtype: 'panel', 
   baseCls: 'overlay-panel', // it styles the overlay panel and not the underlying mask    
   modal: {        
       id: 'myModalClass',      
       style:'background-color:black;opacity:0.8;top:125px;'     
      },
```

I could see the bgcolor and opacity getting applied.
But I am unable to override the attribute ' top = 0px !important '
Kindly provide your valuable suggestions , TIA !

Answer (score 0):

go with your panel, but instead use the following values:

```
xtype: 'container',
top: 125,
bottom: 0,
left: 0,
right: 0,
style: 'background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8)'
```

basically it's only important to set the top value and the other values can be set inside your css.
That will create a floating container (or panel if needed).

But on the other side you could also use:

```
Ext.Viewport.setMasked({xtype:'loadmask',message:'goto heaven', top:125});
```